# logging file does not exist when running in celery

Tags: python, django, logging

first, I'm sorry about my low level english

I create a website for study

I create send SMS feature using django + redis + celery

**tasks/send_buy_sms.py**

```
from celery import Task
from items.utils import SendSMS

class SendBuyMessageTask(Task):

    def run(self, buyer_nickname, buyer_phone, saler_phone, selected_bookname):
        sms = SendSMS()
        sms.send_sms(buyer_nickname, buyer_phone, saler_phone, selected_bookname)
```

**items/utils.py**

```
import os
import requests
import json


class SendSMS():

    def send_sms(self, buyer_nickname, buyer_phone, saler_phone, selected_bookname):
        appid = [...]
        apikey = [...]

        sender = '...'
        receivers = [saler_phone, ]

        content = '...'

        url = os.environ.get("URL")

        params = {
            'sender': sender,
            'receivers': receivers,
            'content': content,
        }
        headers = {...}
        r = '...'

        return params
```

when I send sms using my code it has no problem

`[2017-09-12 17:20:43,532: WARNING/Worker-6] Task success`

and I want make log file and insert log "success send SMS" when user click "send sms button"

**wef/wef/decorators.py**

```
from django.utils import timezone
import logging

def log_decorator(func):

    logging.basicConfig(filename='../../sendsms.log', level=logging.INFO)

    def wrap_func(self, *args, **kwargs):
        time_stamp = timezone.localtime(timezone.now()).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
        logging.info('[{}] success send SMS'.format(time_stamp))
        print(logging)
        return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrap_func
```

but when I click 'send sms' button task is Ok , but log file doesn't created...

So I want to know 'what is the problem?'

I change my code `create logfile` -> `print log`

**wef/wef/decorators.py**

```
from django.utils import timezone

def log_decorator(func):

    def wrap_func(self, *args, **kwargs):
        time_stamp = timezone.localtime(timezone.now()).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
        ## print log
        print('[{}] succes send sms'.format(timestamp))
        ## print log
        return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrap_func
```

when I click 'send sms button' the log print in celery

[image]

I'm so confused because print() is working but create log file doesn't working...

I think my code(create logging file) is no problem because when I practice create log file without django,celery,redis, log file was created successfully

same code, same feature but not working in django and celery

please give me some advise thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have to add logger like -

```
# import the logging library
import logging

# Get an instance of a logger
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def my_view(request, arg1, arg):
    ...
    if bad_mojo:
        # Log an error message
        logger.error('Something went wrong!')
```

Here I am assuming that you have configured your loggers, handlers, filters and formatters

For more information visit [URL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/logging/)